# CSS Sidebar not applying all stylesheet rules

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I started building my main page with a sidebar, the menus appear on the left, no issue on that side, but the sidebar background and width are not working and I'm left with just the menus titles and submenus only...

This is the plain and simple page I'm building and this is the stylesheet file, the issue is after the Side Bar comment section, it doesn't execute...

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background: #fafafa;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}


/* Side Bar */

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  background: #7386D5;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/js/all.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <nav id="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <h3>Bootstrap Slider</h3>
    </div>
    <ul class="lisst-unstyled components">
      <p>The Providers</p>
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
        <ul class="Collapse lisst-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Pages</a>
        <ul class="collapse lisst-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Page 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Page 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Policy</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div id="content">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
              <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
              <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
            </button>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <br><br>
    <h2>Collapsible Sidebar using Bootstrap 5</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate repellat quaerat recusandae adipisci voluptate soluta tenetur ex possimus, ipsa numquam eius, ullam distinctio. In similique delectus, ut numquam quas consequuntur!
    </p>

    <div class="line"></div>
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia quidem laboriosam amet, nam vel officiis placeat ipsum reprehenderit iste minus quisquam molestiae necessitatibus? Provident fugiat, architecto praesentium hic quidem aliquam.</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-SR1sx49pcuLnqZUnnPwx6FCym0wLsk5JZuNx2bPPENzswTNFaQU1RDvt3wT4gWFG" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

What am I missing so I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you schould change `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">` to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/style.css">`.

Comment: no I can access the css file, it's the part after the comment that is not loading